# Container margin not transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my flutter project i have an `AnimatedContainer` which is my `BottomAppBar`. If i give it a `margin` to space it from the screen egdes the `margin` is not transparent so it is visible when something is behind it (picture). I could now separate the container from the screen edges using e.g. a `SizedBox` but i dont feel like that is good practice.
My question is how i can make that margin transparent so that the Container is still spaced from the edge but that there is also nothing covering the text.

the margin covers the text as you can see on this picture

[image]

**Code:**
*main.dart:*

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider())],
      child: const MainWidget()));
}
```

*main_widget.dart:*

```
class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: ((context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: FloatingBottomAppBar(),
          body: child,
        );
      }),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Test App",
      themeMode: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode,
      theme: Themes.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: Themes.darkTheme,
      home: const GroupScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

*floating_ab.dart:*

```
class FloatingBottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const FloatingBottomAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey),
            ],
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
              Icon(Icons.search),
              Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              Icon(Icons.notifications),
              Icon(Icons.person)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

*group_screen.dart:*

```
class GroupScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GroupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Groups",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
         children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return Center(
                      child: Text("$index",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30)));
                }),
                itemCount: 50),
          ),
        ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
setting `extendBody: true` in the scaffold should fix it

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the code as text using the Code Sample option in the editor {}, this will be useful to reproduce the code and many other benefits.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: added the code, thanks for the fast response

Comment: You can followdulak answer , also you can try `floatingActionButton` in replace of `bottomNavigationBar`

Comment: yeah i have already tried that, it works but i dont think thats the good way to to it. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `extendBody: true` in your `Scaffold`

Comment: Maybe. Did you put that in both Scaffolds?